# How can I align divs in a row rather than vertically?

Tags: html, css

I need help with some issues with the `<div>` element using `CSS/HTML`.

## 1: `div` align

Examples are better than words, so I have a simple CSS example: http://jsfiddle.net/wmyxn7L8/
How do I force that when I add a second (the same) div, it will place it on the left of the first one and not under the first div. Here is how I don't want it to be: http://jsfiddle.net/dva4jgt1/ (divs are under the previous one).

## 2: Max `div`s per row

How can I set that when I add, for example 5 `div`s, the 6th will be under it (like e-shops). New `div`s should be added at the beginning, center, or at the end of `body`.

Comment: Include the relevant code ***in*** the question... Don't try to hack the question system that warned you not to post fiddle links without code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work out for you.

```css
.something {
     background-color: black;
     width: 200px;
     height: 120px;
     margin:4px 6px;
     float:left;
}
.something:nth-child(5){
     clear:left;
}
```

float left on .something will stack the next div you add next to it.

nth-child(5) selects the 5th div and uses clear left so that no other elements can float next to it, forcing them to the next line.

Comment: could also use nth-child(5n+1) to select every 5th div if you plan on having many.

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you also help me with this? http://jsfiddle.net/p4256303/ - I would like to make div overlay the div under it instead of pushing/scrolling it.

Answer (score 1):

first div should have the style of position relative.
The overlay div should be inside the first div with a position of absolute something like this

```html
<div id="base" style="position: relative;">
     <div id="overlay" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
          The overlay text
     </div>
     The base Div
</div>
```

You can position the overlay to taste and add width and height attributes to the css. You can move the css to a style sheet.  I only put 'id's in the divs for relevancy you can leave them off or use your own to create handles to a style sheet and move the css from inline to a style sheet.